# clearing airflow tasks results in error (mushroom cloud) with TypeError: can't pickle SSLContext objects

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, airflow

I am testing out an airflow (version 1.10.5 and python 3) DAG and noticed that whenever I try to Clear a task, it results in the mushroom cloud and says that SSLContext object can't be serialized.

This seems to happen no matter the state of the task -- however, if I manually Mark as Failed and then Clear, it seems to work fine.

Not sure what is going on -- any insight on this would be most appreciated! Thank you

Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 258, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 281, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 328, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 1261, in clear
    include_upstream=upstream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1051, in sub_dag
    for t in regex_match + also_include}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1051, in <dictcomp>
    for t in regex_match + also_include}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 161, in deepcopy
    y = copier(memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 626, in __deepcopy__
    setattr(result, k, copy.deepcopy(v, memo))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: can't pickle SSLContext objects
```

-- EDIT --

So I did more digging and I think it is because a task in my DAG uses googleads to make calls to its API. That lib uses SSLContext and it seems like that is what is causing this issue (https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/f070075a081cf2b32fd3d3b1b34b3e3770858c52/googleads/common.py#L440)

Not sure but is there anyway in airflow application code to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Did you set an hook or a connection in the constructor of one of your operators in your DAG?

If yes, try to set this hook/connection directly on the beginning of the `execute` method and remove it from the `__init__` method.

The **PostgresOperator** is a good example.
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/postgres_operator.py#L65-L67